# Crashlytics reports EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS. No traces of source

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics

I am receiving a Crashlytics report but it doesn't contain anything that could help me identify which part of my application is crashing.

Here's the complete downloaded .txt report from Crashlytics

```html
# Crashlytics - plaintext stacktrace downloaded by User at Mon, 23 Jan 2017 06:25:47 GMT
# URL: https://fabric.io/user/ios/apps/com.myapp.bundleidentifier/issues/57c72fb40aeb16625b814d60/sessions/3000505bf0e34fd3bcd6e9cabdecada3_7d537631c1fd41e9bb6d83e1f2a8b6dd_0_v1
# Organization: User
# Platform: ios
# Application: Hajj
# Version: 1.0.4 (1)
# Bundle Identifier: com.myapp.bundleidentifier
# Issue #: 2
# Issue ID: 57c72fb40aeb16625b814d60
# Session ID: 3000505bf0e34fd3bcd6e9cabdecada3_7d537631c1fd41e9bb6d83e1f2a8b6dd_0_v1
# Date: 2017-01-22T10:14:11Z
# OS Version: 10.2.0 (14C92)
# Device: iPhone 5s
# RAM Free: 7.4%
# Disk Free: 9.5%

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Template                       0x10043013c std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int> > >::destroy(std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, void*>*) + 4299620668
1  Template                       0x100430148 std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int> > >::destroy(std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, void*>*) + 4299620680
2  Template                       0x100430148 std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int> > >::destroy(std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, void*>*) + 4299620680
3  Template                       0x100477548 opengl::GLProgram::~GLProgram() + 4299912520
4  Template                       0x100430148 std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int> > >::destroy(std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, void*>*) + 4299620680
5  Template                       0x10047771c opengl::GLProgram::~GLProgram() + 4299912988
6  Template                       0x10046d1e8 opengl::detail::GLStateMachine::~GLStateMachine() + 4299870696
7  Template                       0x10046bd74 opengl::detail::GLStateMachine::~GLStateMachine() + 4299865460
8  libsystem_c.dylib              0x1855ffff0 __cxa_finalize_ranges + 392
9  libsystem_c.dylib              0x1855a9390 exit + 24
10 UIKit                          0x18c5fe7fc +[_UIAlertManager hideAlertsForTermination] + 490
11 UIKit                          0x18c8007cc __102-[UIApplication _handleApplicationDeactivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.2100 + 792
12 UIKit                          0x18c803fdc _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 292
13 UIKit                          0x18c7f5d50 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 560
14 UIKit                          0x18c5650b4 _afterCACommitHandler + 168
15 CoreFoundation                 0x18666a0c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
16 CoreFoundation                 0x186667cf0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
17 CoreFoundation                 0x186668180 __CFRunLoopRun + 1024
18 CoreFoundation                 0x1865962b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
19 GraphicsServices               0x18804a198 GSEventRunModal + 180
20 UIKit                          0x18c5dd7fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
21 UIKit                          0x18c5d8534 UIApplicationMain + 208
22 Template                       0x10006affc main (main.m:14)
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x1855795b8 (Missing)

--

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  Template                       0x10043013c std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int> > >::destroy(std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, void*>*) + 4299620668
1  Template                       0x100430148 std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int> > >::destroy(std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, void*>*) + 4299620680
2  Template                       0x100430148 std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int> > >::destroy(std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, void*>*) + 4299620680
3  Template                       0x100477548 opengl::GLProgram::~GLProgram() + 4299912520
4  Template                       0x100430148 std::__1::__tree<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, std::__1::less<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >, true>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int> > >::destroy(std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::__value_type<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, int>, void*>*) + 4299620680
5  Template                       0x10047771c opengl::GLProgram::~GLProgram() + 4299912988
6  Template                       0x10046d1e8 opengl::detail::GLStateMachine::~GLStateMachine() + 4299870696
7  Template                       0x10046bd74 opengl::detail::GLStateMachine::~GLStateMachine() + 4299865460
8  libsystem_c.dylib              0x1855ffff0 __cxa_finalize_ranges + 392
9  libsystem_c.dylib              0x1855a9390 exit + 24
10 UIKit                          0x18c5fe7fc +[_UIAlertManager hideAlertsForTermination] + 490
11 UIKit                          0x18c8007cc __102-[UIApplication _handleApplicationDeactivationWithScene:shouldForceExit:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.2100 + 792
12 UIKit                          0x18c803fdc _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 292
13 UIKit                          0x18c7f5d50 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 560
14 UIKit                          0x18c5650b4 _afterCACommitHandler + 168
15 CoreFoundation                 0x18666a0c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
16 CoreFoundation                 0x186667cf0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
17 CoreFoundation                 0x186668180 __CFRunLoopRun + 1024
18 CoreFoundation                 0x1865962b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
19 GraphicsServices               0x18804a198 GSEventRunModal + 180
20 UIKit                          0x18c5dd7fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
21 UIKit                          0x18c5d8534 UIApplicationMain + 208
22 Template                       0x10006affc main (main.m:14)
23 libdispatch.dylib              0x1855795b8 (Missing)

#1. com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18566d188 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18566cff8 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18666a5d0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1866681ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1865962b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5  Foundation                     0x1870d326c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  Foundation                     0x1870f3dd0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7  UIKit                          0x18cf51c38 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8  Foundation                     0x1871d0e68 __NSThread__start__ + 1024
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x185751850 _pthread_body + 240
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x185751760 _pthread_body + 282
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18574ed94 thread_start + 4

#2. com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18566d188 mach_msg_trap + 8
1  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18566cff8 mach_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18666a5d0 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 192
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1866681ec __CFRunLoopRun + 1132
4  CoreFoundation                 0x1865962b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
5  CFNetwork                      0x186d9b8f0 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 336
6  Foundation                     0x1871d0e68 __NSThread__start__ + 1024
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x185751850 _pthread_body + 240
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x185751760 _pthread_body + 282
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18574ed94 thread_start + 4

#3. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
0  Template                       0x1000fbc30 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4296260656
1  Template                       0x1000fbc30 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4296260656
2  Template                       0x1000fbaec CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4296260332
3  Template                       0x1000ec2ac CLSHandler + 4296196780
4  Template                       0x1000e7250 CLSMachExceptionServer + 4296176208
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x185751850 _pthread_body + 240
6  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x185751760 _pthread_body + 282
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18574ed94 thread_start + 4

#4. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18568ba88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18574f344 _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18574ed8c start_wqthread + 4

#5. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18568ba88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18574f160 _pthread_wqthread + 968
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18574ed8c start_wqthread + 4

#6. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18568ba88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18574f344 _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18574ed8c start_wqthread + 4

#7. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18568ba88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18574f160 _pthread_wqthread + 968
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18574ed8c start_wqthread + 4

#8. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18568ba88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18574f344 _pthread_wqthread + 1452
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18574ed8c start_wqthread + 4

#9. Thread
0  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18574ed88 start_wqthread + 126

#10. Thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x18568ba88 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18574f160 _pthread_wqthread + 968
2  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18574ed8c start_wqthread + 4
```

> The application is written Swift 2.3

Can anyone please help me understand how can I even start locating the actual code causing this crash.

Thanks

Comment: I have no experience with Crashlytics, but the most common reason for crashes is that the OpenGL context can get unloaded when you switch between applications. Does your program detect that and reupload the textures, etc.?